# How to use Deelang conditionals with operators?

Tags: java, android, scripting

Am making a simple game (another one that will probably never be published) in libGdx and I want to evaluate 'events' for the game characters. Each event should have a 'condition' block and an 'execute' block, that executes if the 'condition' returns true. The language has to support order of operations as well as the following logical operators or their equivalents;

`==`

`!=`

`<=`

`>=`

`||`

`&&`

I also need to be able to pass instances of various objects to the script, so that I might access variables and call methods similar to this;

```
if(game.hasFlag("here_be_my_flag")) then
    game.alertAllPlayers("Here be my flag!");
```

Where `game` is the instance of class `Game` of my game and `hasFlag` and `alertAllPlayers` are methods of `game` implemented in java.

The problem comes when I need two dozen scripts evaluating for each "character" (between 100 and 500) in the game. It was quite simple to set Mozilla's Rhinoscript Javascript interpreter up for this, but this slows my FPS down from 50 to the 25 to 30 range, an unacceptable loss of performance. This is because Rhino was designed to run on an actual JVM, something Android lacks. Android instead runs on a DVM which executes bytecode in a different format from JVM bytecode. Rhino can compile to Java bytecode, but not Dalvik.

This problem is present in many of the different languages. Most were designed to work on desktop computers. I stumbled upon Deelang, a small scripting language that compiles into Dalvik bytecode. Deelang has [good performance](https://github.com/roscopeco/deelang/wiki/DEX-Compiler-vs.-Dee-VM-Performance) relative to Rhino on Android devices.

Unfortunately, it seems that most languages with good documentation do not have this ability and are bound to be slower than those that do (there are probably exceptions). So, I looked at the two basic examples of Deelang code on Github and there is absolutely nothing on boolean comparisons. I learned of Deelang while reading a few questions on scripting languages in java. There is little to no documentation on the Github Wiki regarding this, so, does anyone with experience in this minilanguage know anything regarding the use of operators and conditionals?

Note that I have poked around in the code for comments that might possible give me an idea as to how to do this.

Comment: Why not use dynamic loading jars? (Plugins). You can always integrate your own bytecode interpreter its way better then scripting javascript, for games in libgdx it would be like js->java->native. In your case it's overkill.

Comment: @3mpty I honestly have not even considered dynamically loading plugins. I will look into it. Do you mean compiling the java extension on runtime, or am I misinterpreting your comment?

Comment: google for 'reflection', 'java loading jar at runtime'. There're few approaches for this problem, but most of them can be simplified to jar with proper api entries that you can call in.

Comment: Anyway is there any good reason for sparated scripts in such way, for single-man-project?